# ¿ Qué es la clase Meta y como funciona en los modelos de Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Quiero saber que es esta clase y como funciona en Django.

```
   class Categorias(models.Model):
        ...
        class Meta:
            ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Las `Meta` clases adentro de los modelos de Django sirven para adosar metadata a dichos modelos. Por ejemplo:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["last_name"]
        verbose_name = "Persona"
        verbose_name_plural = "Personas"
```

Sirven para muchas cosas como, por ejemplo, para definir los permisos habilitados, la base de datos asociada, el nombre de la tabla, el nombre en singular o plural que se va a ver en el admin de Django.

Para ver más al respecto podés entrar a: [documentación oficial de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/)

Vale aclarar que no se deben confundir con las `metaclass` de Python: [documentación oficial de python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)